# Click function on cloned object

Tags: jquery, onclick, clone

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/7Wp9z/9/) fiddle.

Here is the most important markup:

```
$("div#images > img").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).fadeOut("fast").remove();    
        $("div#overlay").fadeOut("fast");
    }
    else {
        $(this).clone().addClass("active").appendTo("div#images");
        var marginL = -$("div#images > img.active").width() / 2;
        $("div#images > img.active").css("margin-left", marginL);

        $("div#overlay").fadeIn("fast");
    }
});​
```

### What I want

When a user clicks an image, jQuery should clone that image and immediately open it up in a lightbox-style pop-up. (I do NOT want to use plugins for this.) This works fine. But, I also want that when a user clicks that cloned image that the image is removed and that the overlay fades out again. This doesn't work at all.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function hideClone() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast").remove();
    $("#overlay").fadeOut("fast");
}

$("#images").on('click', 'img', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $div = $this.closest('div'),
        $clone = $this.clone(),
        marginL = $clone.width() / -2;
    $clone.addClass("active").css("margin-left", marginL).appendTo($div).on('click', hideClone);
    $("#overlay").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Wp9z/53/)**

Answer (score 1):

As the object is a live object and changes you need to change the .click function to .live function like this:

```
$("div#images > img").click(function() {...
```

To this:

```
$("div#images > img").live('click',function() {...
```

Here the jsFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wp9z/52/
Hope that helps

Comment: I chose Beetroot's solution because it's much shorter than my own code and it works. Yours works as well. +1 for that. Can you explain what this 'live object' means?

Comment: `.live` is deprecated, and has been replaced with `.on`.